# Do Pthirus gorillae remain in gorilla leaf nests after gorillas migrate and abandon them?

Tags: ecology, behaviour, mammals, parasitology

Gorillas [build leaf nests to sleep in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nest-building_in_primates#In_gorillas). Do the lice which parasitise gorillas, [*Pthirus gorilla*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pthirus_gorillae), remain in gorilla leaf nests after gorillas migrate to new regions (and abandon the old nests)?

Answer (score 1):

From the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pthirus_gorillae) on *Pthirus gorillae*: "Researchers theorize that humans acquired the parasite while butchering or scavenging on gorilla corpses, or **sleeping in the abandoned sleeping nests of gorillas**".

So yes, they are believed to remain.